# rPi Python, seatalk1 to nmea 0183

Tags: python, parsing

Hello I'm new to programing.

Below datagrams are from http://www.thomasknauf.de/rap/seatalk2.htm
And these are some samples which i have to translate to nmea0183.
Can anyone kindly do some of the parsing in python?

Final program will get the seatalk1 data when sent and translate it to nmea0183 then display it on screen.
seatalk1 data will come from https://github.com/Thomas-GeDaD/Seatalk1-Raspi-reader
Thank you

```
 00  02  YZ  XX XX  Depth below transducer: XXXX/10 feet
                   Flags in Y: Y&8 = 8: Anchor Alarm is active
                              Y&4 = 4: Metric display units or
                                       Fathom display units if followed by command 65
                              Y&2 = 2: Used, unknown meaning
                  Flags in Z: Z&4 = 4: Transducer defective
                              Z&2 = 2: Deep Alarm is active
                              Z&1 = 1: Shallow Depth Alarm is active
                Corresponding NMEA sentences: DPT, DBT
```

or

```
 10  01  XX  YY  Apparent Wind Angle: XXYY/2 degrees right of bow
             Used for autopilots Vane Mode (WindTrim)
             Corresponding NMEA sentence: MWV
```

or

```
 11  01  XX  0Y  Apparent Wind Speed: (XX & 0x7F) + Y/10 Knots
             Units flag: XX&0x80=0    => Display value in Knots
                         XX&0x80=0x80 => Display value in Meter/Second
             Corresponding NMEA sentence: MWV
```

or

```
 50  Z2  XX  YY  YY  LAT position: XX degrees, (YYYY & 0x7FFF)/100 minutes
                 MSB of Y = YYYY & 0x8000 = South if set, North if cleared
                 Z= 0xA or 0x0 (reported for Raystar 120 GPS), meaning unknown
                 Stable filtered position, for raw data use command 58
                 Corresponding NMEA sentences: RMC, GAA, GLL
```

or

```
 53  U0  VW      Course over Ground (COG) in degrees:
             The two lower  bits of  U * 90 +
                the six lower  bits of VW *  2 +
                the two higher bits of  U /  2 =
                (U & 0x3) * 90 + (VW & 0x3F) * 2 + (U & 0xC) / 8
             The Magnetic Course may be offset by the Compass Variation (see datagram 99) to get the Course Over Ground (COG).
             Corresponding NMEA sentences: RMC, VTG
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved it.

```
## AWS, Apparent Wind Speed  
                    elif st_header == '11':
                        try:
                            a1,a2,a3,a4,a5 = st_data.split(',')
                        except ValueError: a1="none"
                        else:
                            xx = int(a4, 16)
                            y = (int(a5, 16)) & 15 # 0Y - & with 0x0F (15) to ensure that we get rid of first octet, it might be unnecessary 
                            isInKnots = (xx & 128 == 128)
                            speed = float(xx & 127) + y/10
                            if (isInKnots) :
                                aws_read = speed * 0.514444691
                            else :
                                aws_read =  speed
                            print('aws_read',aws_read)
```